# Updating the value of a iterator tag in struts2

Tags: java, ajax, struts2

I have a jsp in which I have a drop down as

```
<s:select name="newQuestion.CertificationId" list="certificationList"
          listKey="certificationId" listValue="certificationName" 
          headerKey="" headerValue="Select Certification" 
          label="Certification Name"
          onchange="getQuestionsList(this.value)" />
```

When the dropdown value changes I can `getQuestionsList`. In the javascript function I submit to an action class where I modify the value of a **questionList** which is displayed in my JSP via an iterator.

The values of the **questionList** contain all questions and when I select a value from the above drop down I need to populate only those questions which belong to the id selected in the drop down. (I query the DB to load the questions in action class.)

Initially when the page is loaded I have all questions in **questionList** but after selecting a value from drop down I have the updated questions in the action class.

For displaying the values of question list I use a iterator tag

```
<div id="questionDetails" class="registrationDetails" style="display: none;">
  <span><b>Question List</b></span>
  <br>
  <table class="registrationDetailsTable">
    <tr class="tabledataheader">
      <td>Question Id</td>
      <td>Question Description</td>
    </tr>

    <s:iterator value="questionList">
      <tr class="tabledatarow">
        <td><s:property value="questionId" /></td>
        <td><s:property value="questionDesc" /></td>
      </tr>
</s:iterator>
  </table>
</div>
```

The div is initially hidden and on select of a value in drop down I need to display the values of **questionList** which is taking old values as the page is not reloaded.

When I again come back to this jsp I am not seeing the new value as it is not getting updated.

Any heads up please

Comment: if this is ajax, I think it won't be implicitly handled by Struts2's action unless you are using a plugin which support ajax.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try Struts2 Jquery Plugin. [Here](http://www.weinfreund.de/struts2-jquery-showcase/index.action) is the showcase with code.

What you need is

```
<sj:select ...> tag.
```

Let me know if you still need an example.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to make few changes to the code. Let me list them down:

1. Move the following part in your initial JSP to another jsp, say questionList.jsp. The below part should be the only thing which should be inside the newly created jsp.

   ```
     <span><b>Question List</b></span>
     <br>
     <table class="registrationDetailsTable">
       <tr class="tabledataheader">
         <td>Question Id</td>
         <td>Question Description</td>
       </tr>

       <s:iterator value="questionList">
         <tr class="tabledatarow">
           <td><s:property value="questionId" /></td>
           <td><s:property value="questionDesc" /></td>
         </tr>
   </s:iterator>
     </table>
   ```
2. In your main page, you would need to replace the above code part with

   <jsp:include page="questionList.jsp" flush="true"/>
3. Now deploy and see if everything is in place as before.
4. In your `getQuestionsList()` javascript function, make an ajax call to another action mapping say `showQuestionList.action?certification=12`. Here, `12` will be the `id` of the certification, which you will handle in the action. If you use `certification` as an action property, add a variable with the same name with getter and setter methods.
5. In your action method say `showQuestionList()`, retrieve the `questionList` and assign to the action variable.
6. On return of `SUCCESS` of the above method, the result should send only `questionList.jsp`. This will have the part to list just the necessary fields.
7. In the `getQuestionsList()` javascript function, after the ajax call being success, get the data and put it into the div with id `questionDetails`.
8. Show the `div`.